# What should I do to initialize an array of a structure

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I use below way to initialize an array of CandyBar structure, but compiler always says excess elements in struct initializer. I tried putting only one structure initializer in the array definition, it compiled, but the rest 2 elements of the array are null
What should I do?

```
struct CandyBar{
    string brand;
    float weight;
    int calories;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        array<CandyBar, 3> ary_cb =
    {
        {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350},
        {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350},
        {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350}
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a pair of braces around your structures (remember, `std::array` is a struct containing an array):

```
    array<CandyBar, 3> ary_cb =
    {
        { 
            {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350} ,
            {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350} ,
            {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350} 
        }
    };
```

Comment: `remember, std::array is a struct containing an array` This isn't technically guaranteed, either way the braces can be elided as of C++14 although compilers (gcc at least) have yet to catch up.

Comment: Thanks for answering. but if it's an int array, it could be written as array<int,3> a = {2, 3, 4}; don't need the pair of braces I missed?

Answer (score 1):

The Reason why the rest 2 elements of the array are null is because you put all the info in the first candybar element and not the other two candybar elements.

Solution:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{

    array<CandyBar, 3> ary_cb =
    {
        { //Struct
            {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350},
            {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350},
            {"Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350}
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Source - > [Link](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-initializing-array-of-structure/)

Answer (score 0):

As well as quantdev's suggestion this also works (in C++11):

```
array<CandyBar, 3> ary_cb =
{
    "Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350 ,
    "Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350 ,
    "Mocha Munch", 2.3, 350 
};
```

You have to leave out either all the braces or none, when initializing a nested set of aggregates (i.e. struct / array).